# Resetting data everyday on android app as an asyn task

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have an app that needs to reset its text fields and other views everyday. Its like a daily tasks that remain constant but the progress has to be reset everyday or at 12am

Comment: What do you mean "reset" the text fields? How are you storing the data that they are not already reset when the app is recreated?

Comment: @cricket_007 by using shared perferences. By reset i mean reset the text of textview by setText method

Comment: So, can you store the current date, then "tomorrow", when the app is opened, just do some simple math to compare the stored and current date, then do your logic? Maybe you are over thinking the need for an automatic / background solution like the answer below

Comment: Actually my concept is a bit different

Answer (score 0):

That a really easy task to implement using AlarmManager.

Following [this guide](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html) it should be easy for you.

Example:

```
//define your intent
AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
PedingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);


// Set the alarm to start at approximately 00:00 h(24h format).
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 00);
//repeteat alarm every 24hours
alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);
```

Now create a BroadcastReceiver called "AlarmReceiver" and inside it, do whatever you want to.

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
{    
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {   
        //do whatever you want.
    }
}
```

Maybe you should use a [WakefulBroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html) depending of your task.

Comment: I am not able to call getSharedPreference(key, int); inside the onRecieve. What can i do?

Comment: How are you doing it? You have to do it by : "context.getSharedPreference(key, int);"